# What is the opposite of the verb "animate"?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of the verb *animate*? I am looking for something meaning "take life out of something."

Comment: vegitate  (just kidding, I think)

Comment: How about 'defenestrate?' (or maybe 'exfenestrate' :-)

Comment: Why can't you just look this up? A google search yields many results, and the thesaurus is your friend.

Comment: How about *kill*?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is uncommon, but [*disanimate*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disanimate) is a word that means to deprive of life that has the same root as animate plus the Latinate prefix *dis-* which indicates a reversal or negation.

Answer (score 3):

**Depress** is listed as its antonym and can be used depending on the subject.

Comment: Yes, I saw this in the Mac's dictionary as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Deprive
Unnerve
Weaken
Enervate
Devitalize
Debilitate
Exsanguinate
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few:

> Deaden
>   Dampen (as in *his spirits were dampened*)
>   Dispirit
>   Quiet/Quieten (As in *he quieted the man*)

Answer (score 1):

Animate means *movement* and thus the antonym is *freeze*.